# jQuery: detect ajax call

Tags: jquery

Is there a way to detect when one of the plugins successfully completes ajax call using $.ajax.
I am using a treeview plugin that calls asp.net webservice, and I want to attach context menu to the branches/leafs once they've been loaded.

Comment: hook the $.ajax function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked into [`$.ajaxComplete();`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/), [`$.ajaxSuccess();`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSuccess/), or the callback functions within the requests themselves:

```
$.post("somepage.php", {var:"val"}, function(results) {
  /* this is the callback, which happens after the response is received */
  alert(results);
});
```

Take a look at the other [Global Ajax Event Handlers](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/global-ajax-event-handlers/).

Comment: Awesome, I was about to modify the script to create custom event in the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Use the "success" function

```
$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "some.php",
      data: "name=John&location=Boston",
      success: function(msg){
        //the action to be done when the call is complete
      }
   });
```

Comment: I cannot use success function, one plugin does not know about the other one.